# Pandas test reappearance of a value based on the rolling period

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to check if my current `row value - df['ColM']` in the dataframe below appeared in a 5 day look-back period

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['ColN'] = ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']

df['ColM'] = ['XYZ', 'WUV', 'WUV', 'XYZ', 'WUV', 'WUV', 'OPQ', 'XYZ']

df['ColN_dt'] = ['03-12-2018', '03-13-2018', '03-16-2018', '03-18-2018', '03-22-2018', '03-23-2018', '03-26-2018', '03-30-2018']
```

I am trying to see if row value for column `ColM` by `ColN` group ever appeared in last 5 days. i.e. I am looking to create a flag:

```
df['flag'] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a flag column using `groupby`, if your `df['ColN_dt']` is a `datetime` Series:

```
# Set df['ColN_dt'] to datetime:
df['ColN_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColN_dt'])
# Make sure dates are sorted (they are in your example, but just in case)
df.sort_values('ColN_dt', inplace=True)
# Create your flag column
df['flag'] = (df.groupby(['ColN', 'ColM'])['ColN_dt']
              .apply(lambda x: x.diff() < pd.Timedelta(days=5))
              .astype(int))
```

This returns:

```
>>> df
  ColN ColM    ColN_dt  flag
0  AAA  XYZ 2018-03-12     0
1  AAA  WUV 2018-03-13     0
2  AAA  WUV 2018-03-16     1
3  ABC  XYZ 2018-03-18     0
4  ABC  WUV 2018-03-22     0
5  ABC  WUV 2018-03-23     1
6  ABC  OPQ 2018-03-26     0
7  ABC  XYZ 2018-03-30     0
```

**Explanation**:

```
df.groupby(['ColN', 'ColM'])['ColN_dt']
```

Groups your dataframe by `ColN` and `ColM`

```
.apply(lambda x: x.diff() < pd.Timedelta(days=5))
```

Checks whether the difference between a row's `['ColN_dt']` in each group is less than 5 days from the row above. This returns a boolean, which you can set to `int` with `.astype(int)`

Comment: I just realized that I don't need to use `.apply`. I can simply do `.diff() < pd.Timedelta(days=5)`. It saves a lot of execution time.